# Half-Life SDK dlls

Tags: c++, sdk

So when modding Half-Life (Or any source game actually), the project builds to a .dll instead of a .exe, and these .dll's are used by the game .exe file. What is in the .exe that uses the .dlls and how does it know how to load models, or how to know what stuff to render?

Comment: Every game (game engine) will be different you need to read the docs for each one.  In general the game (exe) will be loading dlls from either a known location or via a configuration file.  Once loaded the game engine (exe) will call documented entry points in each dll.  The other technique is dll injection but this is more game-hacking rather than game-modding.

Answer (score 0):

Models, materials, and other content are loaded from predetermined folders. For the Source engine, these are described in https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_SDK_Files_and_Directory_Structure

To actually load DLLs and run code from them, the approach is OS specific. On Win32, a C/C++ program will generally use the [`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) function to open the DLL file and copy it into its own memory space, then use the [`GetProcAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) function to find a function pointer to a given section of code in the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The .exe file is the launcher for the game, the engine is usually in a dll file (hw.dll for Half Life, engine.dll and others for Source). Game server DLL implements entity behavior (spawn, think, touch, use) and exports entities to the engine, this is mostly derived from the original Quake, it uses an almost identical system, except that in Quake 1 the game code is contained within compiled scripts.

The game client DLL implements mouse/keyboard input, draws the GUI, implements temporary client side entities. The engine and game DLLs communicate with each other when needed: when loading a map the engine calls spawn methods for all entities that are in the map, when running a frame the engine calls think methods for all entities that are in the server, game DLLs call engine functions in order to achieve most tasks (access the file system, modify renderer behavior, create entities, etc).

The engine knows how to load models because there's an established model format that the engine knows how to load, if you provide a correct model it should get loaded. The engine may query the BSP data to figure out what models the map contains or it may rely on game DLL entity spawn functions, entities can precache their models (load them so they could be used later on).

The game knows what to render by knowing the player's position, server entity info and the map model. Half-Life/Source follow industry standard computer graphics programming procedures (by using a perspective projection) and they either rely on OpenGL/DirectX functions or do it partly themselves. The position of the player and the direction of view are used to generate a 2D image from the 3D world model and 3D entity models.